# Save at same time, error handeling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Let's say I have this simple association:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments # :autosave option is not declared
end
```

And this code:

```
post = Post.new(title: 'ruby rocks')
post.comments.build(body: 'hello world')
post.save # => saves both post and comment
```

What happens if `post` is invalid, does it still create the comment?

What happens if the attached `comment` is invalid, does it still create the post?

I would like that when `comment` or `post` is invalid, it saves nothing. Am I doing the right thing?

Do I need `validates_associated` ?Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the post is invalid, it will not save the associated records. According to the docs on [Active Record Autosave Association](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html):

> Saving of the parent, its associations, and the destruction of marked associations, all happen inside a transaction. This should never leave the database in an inconsistent state.

You do need validates_associated if the child records must be validated also. However be careful to only call `validates_associated` on one side of the association, otherwise you will create a circular reference.

Comment: Means I should use `validates_associated`

Comment: Yes, put validates_associated in your Post model, but not in your Comment model.